# What is the moment generating function of this random variable?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, moment-generating-functions

we are given $n$ independent standard Gaussian random variables $x_i \sim N(0,1)$ and deterministic integer coefficients $c_i\geq 1$. What is the moment generating function of $Z=(\sum_{i=1}^n c_ix_i)^2$.

So since $x_i$ are normally distributed variables if I multiply them by a constant I obtain the normally distributed variables $x_i^\prime \sim N(0, c_i^2)$. The sum of normally distributed random variables is distributed as well, and therefore $\sum_{i=1}^n c_ix_i \sim N(0, \sum c_i^2)$. This means that $Z$ is a chi-squared random variable with one degree of freedom. If $Z$ is centered, then the moment generating function is given by $M(t)=(1-2t)^{-1/2}$. Is $Z$ centered?

Comment: $Ee^{tZ}=\infty$ for all $t >0$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer? Why is it infinite?

Comment: $\sum c_ix_i \sim N(0,\sum c_i^{2})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear combination of independent normal variables is normal. The square of a normal is Gamma. Hence, your variable has a Gamma distribution (see [a Gamma random variable is a sum of squared normal random variables](https://www.statlect.com/probability-distributions/gamma-distribution)). On the same page you can find the mgf of the Gamma (it exists only for certain values of the parameter).

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. Why is it a Gamma and not simply a Chi-squared distribution?

Comment: The square of a normal variable is Chi-square only if the nomal variable in question has variance equal to 1 (and mean equal to 0). In you case the mean is equal to zero but the variance is equal to the sum of the c_i^2, hence the square is Gamma. The latter is basically a re-scaled Chi-square variable

Comment: Ah ok, so the link you posted states "Therefore, a Gamma random variable with parameters $n $ and $h$ can be seen as a sum of squares of n independent normal random variables having mean 0 and variance $h/n$. " I am too having $n$ degrees of freedom. Since my variance is $\sum c_i^2$ I obtain $h=n\sum c_i^2$. And have to plug this in in the moment generating function $M(t)=(1-\frac{2ht}{n})^{-\frac{n}{2}}=(1-2t\sum c_i^2)^{-\frac{n}{2}}$. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. I am having only $1$ degree of freedom. Unfortunately I cannot edit my comment anymore, but let me do this again with $n=1$. Then I obtain $h=\sum c_i^2$ and hence $M(t)=(1-2t\sum c_i^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, both the parametrization and the formula are correct. Upvote would be appreciated

Comment: Great, thank you for your answer.